# Path Based routing using ALB ingress controller

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, aws-alb

I am using ALB ingress controller for my 10 microservices.

But Path based routing is not working . Everytime ingress is creating a new load balancer for each service.

My requirement is to have a single load balancer and then use path based routing to browse to different services.

Please let me know what annotations I am missing and how to achieve this?

Example ingress is attached here which I'm currently using:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: abcd
  namespace: "default"
  annotations:
     kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "alb"
     alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: arn:aws:acmxxxxx
     alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports:
     alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internal
     alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/subnets: subnet-1,subnet-2
     alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/security-groups: sg-1
spec:
  rules:
    - host:    abcd.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /def
            backend:
              serviceName: abcd
              servicePort: 80
```

Comment: Remove the *? The specification is just literal paths but some controllers allow a regex. That’s not a regex though.

Comment: Hi @coderanger - I have updated my ingress code now, it still doesn't work. :(

Comment: Look it up in the AWS console and see what the generated ALB looks like. Should answer your questions.

Answer (score 2):

According to https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-alb-ingress-controller/issues/298
it is not likely to be feasible

the only workable solution is [ingress merge](https://github.com/jakubkulhan/ingress-merge)

there is sample code in [aws blog](https://aws.amazon.com/cn/blogs/china/merging-alb-progress-controller-on-the-eks-platform/)

I haved use them and it works, through sometimes ingress-merge created additional alb, but you could delete it manually.